# Practicable way of reading xml with huge text nodes in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

After encountering xml data files containing huge text nodes,
I looked for some ways to read and evaluate them in my data
processing scripts.

The xml files are 3D co-ordinate files for molecular modeling 
applications an have this structure (example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hoomd_xml version="1.4">
   <configuration>
      <position>
        -0.101000   0.011000  -40.000000
        -0.077000   0.008000  -40.469000
        -0.008000   0.001000  -40.934000
        -0.301000   0.033000  -41.157000
         0.213000  -0.023000  -41.348000
         ...
         ... 300,000 to 500,000 lines may follow  >>
         ...
        -0.140000   0.015000  -42.556000
      </position>

      <next_huge_section_of_the_same_pattern>
        ...
        ...
        ...
      </next_huge_section_of_the_same_pattern>

   </configuration>
</hoomd_xml>
```

Each xml files contains several huge text nodes and has sizes between 60MB and 100MB depending on the contents.

I tried the naíve approch using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) first but the loader would take forever to initially parse the file:

```
...
my $data = $xml->XMLin('structure_80mb.xml');
...
```

and stop with "**internal error: huge input lookup**", so this approach isn't very practicable.

The next try was to use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0018/LibXML.pod) for reading - but here, the initial loader would bail out immediately with error message "**parser error : xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node**".

Befor writing on this topic on *stackoverflow*, I wrote a q&d parser for myself and sent the file through it (after slurping the xx MB xml file into the scalar `$xml`):

```
...
# read the <position> data from in-memory xml file
my @Coord = xml_parser_hack('position', $xml);
...
```

which returns the data of each line as an array, completes within seconds and looks like this:

```
sub xml_parser_hack {
 my ($tagname, $xml) = @_;
 return () unless $xml =~ /^</;

 my @Data = ();
 my ($p0, $p1) = (undef,undef);
 $p0 = $+[0] if $xml =~ /^<$tagname[^>]*>[^\r\n]*[r\n]+/msg; # start tag
 $p1 = $-[0] if $xml =~ /^<\/$tagname[^>]*>/msg;             # end tag
 return () unless defined $p0 && defined $p1;
 my @Lines = split /[\r\n]+/, substr $xml, $p0, $p1-$p0;
 for my $line (@Lines) {
    push @Data, [ split /\s+/, $line ];
 }
 return @Data;
}
```

This works fine so far but cannot considered 'production ready', of course.

**Q: How would I read the file using a Perl module? Which module would I choose?**

Thanks in advance

rbo

---

**Addendum**: after reading choroba's comment, I looked deeper into XML::LibXML.
The opening of the file `my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location =>'structure_80mb.xml');`  works, contrary to what I thought before. The error occurs if I try to access the text node below the  tag:

```
...
while ($reader->read) {
   # bails out in the loop iteration after accessing the <position> tag,
   # if the position's text node is accessed
   #   --  xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node ---
...
```

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.44/Twig.pm - perl module for processing huge XML documents in tree mode.

Comment: How did you open the file with XML::LibXML? It works for me for files of 100MB.

Comment: @choroba - thanks, I checked again - and updated the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to simulate an answer using XML::LibXML.  Try this, and let me know if it doesn't work.  I created an XML doc with more than 500k lines in the `position` element, and I was able to parse it and print the contents of it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => '/perl/test.xml');
my $nodes = $xml->findnodes('/hoomd_xml/configuration/position');
print $nodes->[0]->textContent . "\n";
print scalar(@{$nodes}) . "\n";
```

I'm using [`findnodes`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode) to use an XPath expression to pull out all the nodes that I want.  `$nodes` is just an array ref, so you can loop through it depending on how many nodes you actually have in your document.

Comment: Thanks! But my XML::LibXML 2.0018 Win64 can't load the file. `$xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $fn)` fails immediately w/`parser error : xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node`. Whereas `$xml = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location =>$fn)` loads the file, but doesn't have the method: `Can't locate object method "findnodes" via package "XML::LibXML::Reader"`.

Comment: @rubberboots Can you provide what version of libxml you're using?  You can get it by printing `XML::LibXML::LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION` inside your Perl script.

Comment: I added the `huge` option as proposed by nwellnhof. Now your `findnodes` works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try `XML::LibXML` with the [`huge`](https://metacpan.org/module/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0018/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#huge) parser option:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => 'structure_80mb.xml',
    huge     => 1,
);
```

Or, if you want to use `XML::LibXML::Reader`:

```
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(
    location => 'structure_80mb.xml',
    huge     => 1,
);
```

Comment: This is it! With the `huge` option, combined with Joel's `findnodes` call, the reading and processing is done in seconds via LibXML. Thank you very much!